# Smart UV Project stretching

Tags: uv

I would like to know why Smart UV project stretches UV map? Scale isn't a problem as it is applied. In the picture you can see that sides of the box is unwrapped in a wrong way. I can unwrap manually by marking seams. But I would like to know why Smart UV Project failing here (and in some other different scenarios).

[YouTube video replication of my question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7O79_mnrX-k)

[image]

Comment: Try tweaking the angle limit until you have a result that you like.

Comment: @moonboots
Thanks for reply. But it seems I didn't understand something in your answer or it is not worked out at all  I've added screen recording on my question (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7O79_mnrX-k). I thought myself that stretching was related with not squarish texture, but how to fix it with Smart UV Project I don't know. Even though in video tutorial that I've watched everything was fine

Comment: oops you're right, I thought Smart UV Project made propotional UVs

Comment: so maybe the best would be to resize the canvas size of your image in an image editor (photoshop, krita, gimp...) to make it square rather than rectangular